# BigQuery - Query to find row with same ID in multiple table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

There are 2 table in BigQuery:

[user_info]

```
id    name    country
-----------------
27    jack     USA
48    tom      ENG
50    Kevin    SWD
81    noname   unknown
```

[user_profile]

```
id     email                 subscribed
-------------------------------------
48     test1@gmail.com       false
61     testagain@gmail.com   true
```

And I want to get list of 'id' and 'name' which 'id' exists in both table. In this case, it will be:

```
id    name
---------------------------------
48    tom
```

How can I make query for this process?

Answer (score 1):

Try using exists logic:

```sql
SELECT id, name
FROM user_info ui
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM user_profile up WHERE up.id = ui.id);
```

Or, use an inner join:

```sql
SELECT ui.id, ui.name
FROM user_info ui
INNER JOIN user_profile up
    ON up.id = ui.id;
```